# Get the number of rows inserted in each bulk insert operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, bulkinsert

I am using the bulk insert operation code to insert data from `DataTable` to SQL Table. How can I get the number of rows inserted at every bulk operation?

Suppose I have initially 25 rows of data in the SQL table and now in the `DataTable` there are 10 rows of data to be inserted via bulk insert operation. How can I get the rows inserted?

```
var table = "TBL_FINANCE";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=QD2AOUR;Database=FINANCE; uid=sa; Password=neptune; Initial Catalog=FINANCE;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI; pooling=false"))
{
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table;
    conn.Open();
    var schema = conn.GetSchema("Columns", new[] { null, null, table, null });
    foreach (DataColumn sourceColumn in dt.Columns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        {
            if (string.Equals(sourceColumn.ColumnName, (string)row["COLUMN_NAME"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(sourceColumn.ColumnName, (string)row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    try
    {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Error with Insert Operation...";
        div_message.Visible = true;
        div_message.Attributes.Add("class", "callout callout-danger");
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        bulkCopy.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlBulkCopy supports notifications

```
  using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connectionString))
{
    sqlBulk.NotifyAfter = 1000;
    sqlBulk.SqlRowsCopied += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("Wrote " + eventArgs.RowsCopied + " records.");
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Employees";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

[system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied?view=netframework-4.7.2)

[using-sqlbulkcopy-for-fast-inserts](https://programmingwithmosh.com/csharp/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-fast-inserts/)